# Azure TokenCache not stored in database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I am building a web app that will run on Azure and it will use AAD authentication.

The code I am using to store and get the token from the cache is here:
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/09/the-new-token-cache-in-adal-v2/
(the second example). I use a database in azure for my table of tokens.

When I run my project locally it works just fine. It writes the token to the table and gets it back whenever it is needed. But when I publish the application to azure it will not write the token. It can connect to the database (I already tested it) but it will not write any token.
While line "if (this.HasStateChanged)" should be true it is false and I got no idea why.

Anyone had a similar problem or a solution on that?

**EDIT:**

Here is some logging:
This one is generated locally:
[image: local log]

And the one generated from the published app:

[image]

I hope it helps

Comment: where do you save the token? If you publish the web app to Azure web app, please make sure you have permission to save the token. We can use [remote debug](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/09/22/remote-debug-your-azure-app-service-web-app/) to set break point to find out the detailed reason.

Comment: The token is stored on an SQL Server which is on Azure as well. And the application has permission to access the database as it saves all other items